# System.MethodAccessException Only on winhost server. Works on development

Tags: vb.net, exception, data-binding, repeater, live

`Attempt by method 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols+Container.InvokeMethod(Method, System.Object[], Boolean[], System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' to access method 'System.Data.Objects.MaterializedDataRecord.get_Item(System.String)'` failed.

I get this System.MethodAccessException error when i run on a winhost server. When I run on built in vs it works fine. Seems to be happening in multiple places wherever i use

```
 <%# Container.DataItem("Something")%>
```

Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Installed versions of .Net server vs your dev box?

Answer (score 2):

Enable full trust in your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<trust level="Full" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```